# JAX-WS in RAD with websphere7 javaAccessorNotSet error

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws, websphere-7

```
SEVERE: javaAccessorNotSet
```

java.net.MalformedURLException: /WEB-INF/wsdl/TestWebServiceService.wsdl does not exist in the module.
    at com.tcs.testwebservice.TestWebServiceService.(TestWebServiceService.java:27)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
    at com.tcs.testwebservice.TestWebServicePortProxy$Descriptor.(TestWebServicePortProxy.java:38)
    at com.tcs.testwebservice.TestWebServicePortProxy.(TestWebServicePortProxy.java:86)
    at com.tcs.testwebservice.client.CheckResponseClient.main(CheckResponseClient.java:12)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPortModel(WSServiceDelegate.java:571)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:274)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:268)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:103)
    at com.tcs.testwebservice.TestWebServiceService.getTestWebServicePort(TestWebServiceService.java:49)
    at com.tcs.testwebservice.TestWebServicePortProxy$Descriptor.initCommon(TestWebServicePortProxy.java:48)
    at com.tcs.testwebservice.TestWebServicePortProxy$Descriptor.(TestWebServicePortProxy.java:39)
    at com.tcs.testwebservice.TestWebServicePortProxy.(TestWebServicePortProxy.java:86)
    at com.tcs.testwebservice.client.CheckResponseClient.main(CheckResponseClient.java:12)

I created JAX-WS service in RAD with websphere 7 server it's working fine when i tested via SOAP UI , but i created client proxcy but am getting above error when i invoke from client.
Here the client code .

public class CheckResponseClient {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TestWebServicePortProxy testWebServicePortProxy = new TestWebServicePortProxy();
    System.out.println("webservice Response"+testWebServicePortProxy.checkGender("MALE"));

}
```

Comment: Looks like your client has wrong path to wsdl - java.net.MalformedURLException: /WEB-INF/wsdl/TestWebServiceService.wsdl does not exist in the module. at com.tcs.testwebservice.TestWebServiceService.(TestWebServiceService.java:27). Maybe you generated web client, instead of java client.

Comment: I need to test it via Web client only , please share the guideline link if you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have some resources on creating web service clients using RAD:

[Rational Application Developer V7.5 Programming Guide](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/Redbooks.nsf/RedbookAbstracts/sg247672.html?Open) - chapter 18
[Web Services Guide](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247758.html?Open) - chapter 4

In short, Switch to the Services view, right-click the your service, select Generate > Client. You should be able to create new web application with jsp files that will be client to your service.

Comment: thanks a lot for your support,I successfully created client but while run the client jsp page i'm getting error below.

Comment: E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet /sampleBankCustomerCheckPortProxy/Result.jsp in application JAXWSCustomerClientEAR. Exception created : com.ibm.websphere.servlet.error.ServletErrorReport: **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.ws.wstx.handler.WSATGenerator &#40;initialization failure&#41;** at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:695) at com.ibm._jsp._Result._jspService(_Result.java:372)

Comment: You need to provide full stack trace. It should include Cause By reason, why the initialization is failing.